# How to convert a FBX made by blender 2.8 into a `g3db/g3dj` file?

Tags: libgdx

I've tried to convert a simple cube with libGDX  [FBX-Converter](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv) but the cube is't displaying in my game app.

The FBX file is created with blender 2.8

On the other hand, if I make an FBX file with blender 2.76 and then convert it to g3dj file it displays successfully.

The only difference between the working one vs the not working one is attribute `TEXCOORD0`

heres 2 `g3dj` files, the one made with blender 2.76, and the one made with blender 2.8

**This is the one that works, FBX created with blender 2.76 and then converted to `g3dj`**

```
{
    "version": [  0,   1], 
    "id": "", 
    "meshes": [
        {
            "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL"], 
            "vertices": [
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000
            ], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": "Cube.002_part1", 
                    "type": "TRIANGLES", 
                    "indices": [
                          0,   1,   2,   2,   1,   3,   4,   5,   6,   6,   5,   7, 
                          8,   9,  10,  10,   9,  11,  12,  13,  14,  14,  13,  15, 
                         16,  17,  18,  17,  19,  18,  20,  21,  22,  21,  20,  23
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "materials": [
        {
            "id": "Material.005", 
            "ambient": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
            "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "opacity":  1.000000, 
            "specular": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000], 
            "shininess":  9.607843
        }
    ], 
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Cube", 
            "rotation": [-0.707107, -0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
            "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  0.158538], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "meshpartid": "Cube.002_part1", 
                    "materialid": "Material.005"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "animations": []
}
```

**And this is the one that do not works, FBX created with blender 2.8 and then converted to `g3dj`**

```
{
    "version": [  0,   1], 
    "id": "", 
    "meshes": [
        {
            "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL", "TEXCOORD0"], 
            "vertices": [
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.750000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.750000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.750000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.750000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.125000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.125000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.875000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.875000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000
            ], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": "Cube.001_part1", 
                    "type": "TRIANGLES", 
                    "indices": [
                          0,   1,   2,   1,   0,   3,   4,   5,   6,   5,   4,   7, 
                          8,   9,  10,   9,   8,  11,  12,  13,  14,  13,  12,  15, 
                         16,  17,  18,  16,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  22,  21,  23
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "materials": [
        {
            "id": "Material.002", 
            "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
            "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "opacity":  0.000000, 
            "specular": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "shininess":  25.000000
        }
    ], 
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Cube", 
            "rotation": [-0.707107, -0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
            "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  0.081716], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "meshpartid": "Cube.001_part1", 
                    "materialid": "Material.002", 
                    "uvMapping": [[]]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "animations": []
}
```

So is there a way to omit this attribute in blender 2.8? or even better make libgdx take into account this attribute?

Im using Diffuse BSDF material in blender 2.8

Comment: Set the opacity to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @Xoppa yes I found about that minutes after posting, but why is the converter is setting opacity to `0`? I need a solution that doesn't require editing the `g3dj` file, as Im using this only to debug, I plan to use `g3db`

Comment: Try setting the opacity to 1 in blender, it might be called alpha and might be part of the materials transparency setting.

Comment: @Xoppa I already tried that, even tho alpha is already set to 1, opacity will be setted to 0, if I set the alpha to 1.1 in blender it will set the opacity to `-0.110000` in `g3dj` if i set the alpha to `0.999` in blender `g3dj` file opacity will be `0.799920`

Comment: this is if I use a texture, if I use Diffuse BSDF material, It wont show alpha option in blender